# StencilJS | Importing a third party script in a component

Tags: javascript, stenciljs

I am trying to use a third party script in a Stencil component which I copied into the build directory. I intend on using stand alone components on various websites. I am not building a Stencil app.

stencil.config.ts

```
export const config: Config = {
  namespace: 'community-component',
  outputTargets: [
    { type: 'dist' },
    { type: 'docs' },
    {
      type: 'www',
      serviceWorker: null // disable service workers
    }
  ],
  copy: [
    { src: 'www/assets/myscript.js', dest: 'assets/js/myscript.js' }
  ]
};
```

Then I import it like this, which is not correct. `myscript.js` also loads jQuery.

```
import * as MyScript from '../../../src/www/assets/myscript.js';
declare const jQuery: any;
```

Now I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`.

Comment: This should be handled same as explained in this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54991630/how-to-fetch-data-from-a-local-json-file-in-stenciljs/55009819#55009819

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use custom scripts in a stencil component, follow these steps:

1. Create an `assets` directory in `src` if it does not exist.
2. Create a new file and paste the contents of your script or just copy and paste your script file.
3. Import the script in your tsx file like this:

   import * as myScript from './assets/my-script.js'
4. Build your component and run.

P.S. - you need not to mention assets folder in copy property of stencil.config.ts. It gets copied by default.

Comment: How about if i want to add the javascripts code in index.html to a separate js file?

Comment: @amirtbi did you figure it out?

Comment: @TomHanlon , yes you can use the answered in this question. Also, you must add the script tag at the end of your index.html